# Exception in thread "main" cucumber.runtime.CucumberException

Tags: selenium, maven, cucumber

I am getting Exception in thread:

```
Exception in thread "main" cucumber.runtime.CucumberException: No back ends were found. Please make sure you have a backend module on your CLASS PATH.
```

I am new for Cucumber BDD framework ,running following feature file.

```
Feature: feature to test login scenario

Scenario: Check login is successful with valid credentials
Given User is on login page
When User enters login and password
And Clicks on login button
Then User navigated to home page
```

I have added following dependencies, tried with different adding version, but still not working.

Kindly provide your help.

Comment: You're using a very old version of Cucumber. So either you're working with an existing project or you are following a very old tutorial. For an up to date tutorial start here https://docs.cucumber.io/docs/guides/10-minute-tutorial/?lang=java if you have a existing project please read very carefully https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask because right now no one can help you.

Comment: @M.P.Korstanje  : Thanks a lot for your reply ! That was really kind of you ! Looks like formatting has gone while submitting my query ! I will keep a note and go through both the given links ! Thanks again !

Comment: It's not about the formatting. To receive help with a problem you need to describe it in such a way that other people can reproduce it. So imagine you delete all your code, what would you do to reproduce the problem again? That's what the second link is about.

Comment: Update the question with the `pom.xml` including cucumber+jdk+Selenium version.